# Specify scope of dependency in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have dependency which is required for unit tests(test scope) and integration tests(it scope), how I can specify 2 scopes in SBT.

```
"com.somelib" % "somelib" % "1.1.1" % "test"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For unit tests:

```
"com.somelib" % "somelib" % "1.1.1" % "test"
```

For integration tests:

```
"com.somelib" % "somelib" % "1.1.1" % "it"
```

For both:

```
"com.somelib" % "somelib" % "1.1.1" % "it,test"
```

More info in the [official docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/offline/Testing.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. 3rd solution is exactly what I need

Comment: The documentation link in the original answer is broken.  [Here is an updated link](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests)